# How to print multiple integers on new lines in Java

Tags: java, output, text-formatting

I am figuring how to **print** the results of 4 integers **on separate lines** by typing **only one** `System.out.println` (I guess typing less is better for coders).

Expected Output :

```
43 
1 
19 
13
```

My code:

```
class JavaApplication1 {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         int a,b,c,d;
         a = -5 + 8 * 6;
         b = (55+9) % 9;
         c = 20 + -3*5 / 8;
         d = 5 + 15 / 3 * 2 - 8 % 3 ;

         System.out.println(a);
         System.out.println(b);
         System.out.println(c);
         System.out.println(d);
    }  
}
```

Comment: To format here, you juste to use "spacebar" on your keyboard ;)

Comment: try to use `System.out.println(a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c + "\n" + d);`

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for YCF_L, how do i vote for you lol ? And yes i used space to format the code, but i need to use space every time on each line ?

Comment: Just vote up and accept one of the answers, they also contain the solution by @YCF_L. You can upvote on comments but it does not count for his reputation or so.

Comment: What do you mean by accept, how do I do this ? Oh i figured .. ok thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do i with several ways :

This will print the variable and between each a `new-line char` :

```
System.out.println(a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c + "\n" + d);
```

---

You can also use method reference and `Arrays`, this will create a dynamic List from the array composed of your 4 variables, and apply `System.out::println` to each one :

```
Arrays.asList(a,b,c,d).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or

```
IntStream.of(a,b,c,d).forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Use a basic `for each loop` can also be a way :

```
for (int i : new int[]{a, b, c, d})
     System.out.println(i);
```

---

Print with `format` also :

```
System.out.printf("%d%n%d%n%d%n%d%n",a,b,c,d)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use '\n' to create a new line in Java, so your code would look like this:

```
System.out.println(a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c + "\n" + d);
```

This will print them on new lines.

Answer (score 2):

> print the results of the 4 integers on separate lines by typing **only once** 'system.out.println'.

Quite easy, you need to add a **new-line character** to the text you want to print. On most machines this is represented by the special character `\n`.

```
String output = a + "\n"
    + b + "\n"
    + c + "\n"
    + d;
System.out.println(output);
```

---

However there are **platform independent** ways like what the method `System.lineSeparator()` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--)) returns. Like:

```
String lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator();
String output = a + lineSeparator
    + b + lineSeparator
    + c + lineSeparator
    + d;
System.out.println(output);
```

---

Alternatively you could use the `System.out.printf` method ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)), which stands for "*print formatted*". It has the parameter `%n` that creates a new line, also using `System.lineSeparator()` internally.

```
System.out.printf("%d%n%d%n%d%n%d%n", a, b, c, d);
```

The `%d` is a placeholder for a number like `int`. It replaces all placeholders by the arguments listed afterwards.

Here is a full list of all parameters the method accepts: [Formatter-Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

---

If you look for a **Java 8** solution using Streams and Lambdas, then you could use this code ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.IntConsumer-)):

```
IntStream.of(a, b, c, d).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

It first creates a **stream** (something like a container in this case) holding your variables and then calls the *print method* **on each** of its elements. Note that the code itself calls the *print method* now **4 times**, **not** only **one time**. But it looks quite compact.

You can view it "*equivalent*" to the following code:

```
int[] values = new int[]{a, b, c, d};

for (int value : values) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't just use `"\n"` which is a linefeed character. This is platform-dependent and if you look at the output containing lines separated by `"\n"` on Windows Notepad, you will not see what you expect.

Use this instead:

```
System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n%s%n%s%n", a, b, c, d);
```

Alternatively:

```
IntStream.of(a, b, c, d).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the first way seems so smart without using the "\n", but i dont really understand it for now, I will read some more about it, but looks like this is the best way !

Comment: @GeorgiMichev Just take a look at the other answers, they explain the method in detail.

Comment: why not forEachOrdered() ?

Comment: @PatrickParker it would make a difference for parallel streams. In general, `forEachOrdered` would be the correct one to use. In this case, I know it is definitely not a parallel stream. If I used `forEachOrdered` there would be no penalty apart from typing a few extra characters.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the newline character. In java it is `\n`
To print them using what you have, it would be:

```
System.out.println(a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c + "\n" + d);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `System.out.format` you can output the system-dependent line separator using the `%n` format; you can also add further number formatting to the format string.

```
 System.out.format("%d%n%d%n%d%n%d%n", a, b, c, d);
```

Answer (score 1):

This satisfies your stated requirement of a single call to `System.out.println`, uses a platform independent line separator, and avoids repetitively typing the same concatenation operation:

```
   System.out.println(IntStream.of(a,b,c,d).mapToObj(Integer::toString)
           .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
```

Here's a more generic version that works for any objects, not only ints:

```
   System.out.println(Stream.of(a,b,c,d).map(Object::toString)
           .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also opt for using `System.out.printf("%d%n%d%n%d%n%d%n",a,b,c,d)`

Answer (score 0):

There are different print statement in java

1.println

`System.out.println(1+"\n"+2+"\n"+3+"\n"+4);`

2.print

`System.out.print("\n"+1);
System.out.print("\n"+2);
System.out.print("\n"+3);
System.out.print("\n"+4);`

3.printf

`System.out.printf("%d%n%d%n%d%n%d%n",1,2,3,4);`

where %d and %n is called format specifier, they specify which type of data will be used in the printf method.
thank you.

---